# How to use multiple sub-routers in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I'm wondering how should I implement the following use case with emberjs:

Imagine an app matching thoses routes:

```
/blog/archives
/blog/article/1
```

In both routes, the user can click on a button which displays the last published comments on the blog in a little modalbox docked in the bottom right corner (it's just an example!).

I want to persist the state of this modalbox based on a hash in the URL:

```
/blog/archives?state=/comments/1
/blog/article/1?state=/comments/1
```

Maybe I need to use multiples routers with each one handling a specific part of the URL.

Is something available for this use case in Ember.js?
How would you do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Ember `Router` is made for be used several times at the same time. Use one router should satisfy all your needs, but...

At this moment, the `Router` does not allow query-string parameters, but I suggest you to take a look at this issues:

- [Router: URL parameters](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1487)
- [Add Query-String support to the Router](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1773) (it will probably supersede the issue above)